# 2 or more arrays from a list

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I am quite not able to get the logic for my requirement.

Lets consider I have an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 3
)
```

I would like to split the below array on the basis if the array element matches its previous element. 
i.e in the above example value at [1] matches the value at [0]. Hence put it into the same array as [0]. Now check if the value at [2] matches the value at [1] if it matches put it into the same array, if not put it into a different array. The process continues.

Below is an example of the desired outpout.

```
Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
         )
 Array
    (
        [0] => 2
     )

     Array
        (
            [0] => 1
         )
     Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 3
         )
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can obtain that result in a loop checking on previous element. the output can be an array of arrays! (or anything you would prefer.. do your thing here)

```
$array1 = array(1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3);
$output_array=array();
$previous_value="";
$output_array_index=0;
foreach ($array1 as $value) {
    if($value != $previous_value){
        $output_array_index+=1;
    }
    $output_array[$output_array_index][]=$value;
    $previous_value=$value;
}
print_r($output_array);
```

so, let me know if you need more pointers! array logic is fun, and php will let you do alot, out of the box. though this specific need is not covered, have a look when you have a minute @ the manual, it'll save you time in the future, guarantee http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: Thank you. Let me try. Give me a minute please.

Comment: I am getting a multidimensional array, with each element separated :(          Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

)

Comment: What a beautiful logic :)

Comment: sorry there i forgot to assign $previous_value=$value; before closing the loop, hope it did not cause you too much of a headache :)

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit confusing but doesn't sound too difficult to implement if I'm understanding it correctly. All you need to do is have a temporary array (or array list) that checks user input. If that user input happens to be the same as the previous input (you can keep a counter variable and check to see if `ArrayList.get(counter) == ArrayList.get(counter-1)`). Keep adding things to this temporary arrayList and once you have a number that is different, just iterate through the arraylist and add it to a new array.

Another question you have to consider is how you are going to store all these arrays. For that you may want to create an ArrayList containing Arrays. That way after you find user input that is different from the previous input you can just use the `toArray` method provided with the ArrayList class and add it to the ArrayList containing all of your separate Arrays!

Hope this helps!